# linphone-iphone sdk is not getting built

Tags: ios, iphone, cmake, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am trying to build SDK for [linphone-iphone](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone).
But, unable to do so. It is giving me an error:

```
"You need at least CMake version 3.3.20150815 but you are currently using
  3.2.3.  There is no Cmake release available for it yet, so you must either
  compile it manually or revert to XCode6 temporary."
```

I am using Xcode 7.1.

Even I don't know how to compile it manually or revert to XCode6 temporary. So, if anybody knows, please help me.

**Note:** I am building it by command "./prepare.py -c && ./prepare.py && make" in linphone-iphone project directory from terminal in Mac OS as per instructions given on https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone.

Comment: `There is no Cmake release available for it yet, so you must either
  compile it manually ...` probably means building CMake from sources. `revert to XCode6 temporary` probably means either downloading XCode6 binaries, or compiling it from sources. All this works are perfectly explained on CMake/XCode sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating linphone submodule:

**`git pull && git submodule update --init --recursive && ./prepare.py -c && make`**

Answer (score 0):

You should install cmake version >= 3.2.3
install them like this:

`brew install cmake`

this will install cmake to **/usr/local/bin** You can check version like this:

`/usr/local/bin/cmake --version`

then you need to reorder your PATH variable:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

after that, you can continue:

```
./prepare.py -c
./prepare.py
make
```